# Moment.js padd 0 if haven't hours or minutes

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I have this code to transform seconds to time

```js
let secs = 5323795;
let duration = moment.duration(Number(secs), "seconds");
let formatted = duration.format("hh:mm:ss");
formatted; // '1.478:49:55'
```

but, if seconfs is less than 1min, the result is

```js
let secs = 35;
let duration = moment.duration(Number(secs), "seconds");
let formatted = duration.format("hh:mm:ss");
formatted; // '35' 

// CORRECT OUTPUT: "00:00:35"
```

How i fix that?

Comment: Add them yourself? ``if (formatted.length === 2) { formatted = `00:00:${formatted}`; } if (formatted.length === 5) { formatted = `00:${formatted}`; }``. Moment.js is no longer maintained, so you should consider looking at a different library.

Comment: @HereticMonkey unfortunately moment is used in a whole project , I can't changed right now.
Your solutions is pretty good. have any native solution ?

Comment: I chose to use
`if (Number(secs) < 60*60) {  return sectToTime(secs)  }  return ; // rest of code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `trim` option in moment duration format to keep all fields, setting trim to false will accomplish this:

```js
let secs = 35;
let duration = moment.duration(Number(secs), "seconds");
let formatted = duration.format("hh:mm:ss", { trim: false });

console.log('Formatted:', formatted)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.3.2/moment-duration-format.min.js" integrity="sha512-ej3mVbjyGQoZGS3JkES4ewdpjD8UBxHRGW+MN5j7lg3aGQ0k170sFCj5QJVCFghZRCio7DEmyi+8/HAwmwWWiA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```